Matrix equation simplification
I have an equation of the form
$\alpha X-X^{-1}=B$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar greater than $0$, $B$ is a matrix, and $X$ is a symmetric matrix.
I'm trying to get the equation to the shape
$X-X^{-1}=C$
where $C$ can be any matrix.
What would be the best approach to do this?

What about multiplying both sides by $1/\sqrt\alpha$?

If you are dealing with complex numbers take one of the roots $\beta^2=\alpha$ and multiply both sides by $\beta^{-1}.$ If you are dealing with real coefficients then in the case $\alpha<0$ it is not possible.

in the problem $\alpha$ will always be greater than 0!

Divide by the square root of $\alpha$.
